# How to Destructure prop in Vuejs template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex

In Vuejs How to destructure props and make code cleaner

I know that Using v-for="({y}) in x" we can destructure but in this case there is no v-for

```
<template>
<div>{{candidate.gender.gender.gender_name}}</div>
<div>{{candidate.name.first_name}}</div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "Candidate",
  props: {
    candidate: Object
  },
  computed: {}
</script>
```

How to destructure and use just {{gender_name}} instead of {{candidate.gender.gender.gender_name}}

candidate is a prop which is being passed from its parent

Answer (score 0):

You could use a computed property. Note that you might have to do some chaining if this property or any of its parent properties might not exist

```js
computed: {
  gender() {
    return this.candidate.gender.gender.gender_name;
  }//chaining:
  gender_safe() {
    return this.candidate && this.candidate.gender && this.candidate.gender.gender && this.candidate.gender.gender.gender_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: any better way than this using object destructuring??